# I have an array of objects and each object has a "user_id" key and I need to get more information from this user in Rethinkdb

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

Hello and thanks to everyone. I'm getting data with reql in rethinkdb. I have a json object, inside this object there is an array of objects called "users". In each of these objects I have an "id" key and I need to obtain more user fields from this "id" and add these fields in the same user object.

This is the code to obtain the information:

```
const id = req.id

r.table("chats").filter(function (chat) { // Get chats
    return chat("users").contains(function (user) {
        return user("id").eq(id)
    })
}).map(function (chat) { // Get messages from every chat
    return chat.merge({
        "messages":
            r.table("messages").eqJoin("user_id", r.table('users'))
                .zip()
                .pluck("id", "creation_date", "message", "email", "username", "status") 
                .orderBy(r.asc('creation_date'))
                .coerceTo('array')
    })
}).run(connection).then(function (cursor) {
    return cursor.toArray()
}).then(function (chats) {
    res.json({ success: 1, chats })
}).catch(function (err) {
    sendError(res, "Error -> " + err)
})
```

And this is the result:

```
{
"success": 1,
"chats": [
    {
        "id": "8c4a58ef-4fb2-4084-af28-d9d04da0651c",
        "image": null,
        "is_group": false,
        "messages": [
            {
                "creation_date": "Fri Dec 21 2018 09:21:17 GMT+0100 (CET)",
                "email": "blabla@sssssss.eu",
                "id": "6c240de3-94e7-4b1c-9ef3-218dc71d8b0a",
                "message": "Felices fiestas por cierto, saludos a la familia",
                "status": "SAVED",
                "username": "John García"
            },
            {
                "creation_date": "Fri Dec 21 2018 09:21:27 GMT+0100 (CET)",
                "email": "eoeoeoeoe@wwwww.eu",
                "id": "72b4350d-a025-4dc1-9038-8e13c3ec12dc",
                "message": "Bien, estoy en la oficina ",
                "status": "SENT",
                "username": "Chester López"
            }
        ],
        "name": null,
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "6c240de3-94e7-4b1c-9ef3-218dc71d8b0a"
            },
            {
                "id": "72b4350d-a025-4dc1-9038-8e13c3ec12dc"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3a3501f3-7a17-4261-a0aa-3cae94f58f18",
        "image": null,
        "is_group": false,
        "messages": [
            {
                "creation_date": "Fri Dec 21 2018 09:21:27 GMT+0100 (CET)",
                "email": "blabla@sssssss.eu",
                "id": "6c240de3-94e7-4b1c-9ef3-218dc71d8b0a",
                "message": "Bien, estoy en la oficina ",
                "status": "SENT",
                "username": "John García"
            },
            {
                "creation_date": "Fri Dec 21 2018 09:22:53 GMT+0100 (CET)",
                "email": "blabla@sssssss.eu",
                "id": "6c240de3-94e7-4b1c-9ef3-218dc71d8b0a",
                "message": "Espero que estéis todos genial",
                "status": "SENDING",
                "username": "John García"
            },
            {
                "creation_date": "Thu Dec 20 2018 16:41:02 GMT+0100 (CET)",
                "email": "eoeoeoeoe@wwwww.eu",
                "id": "72b4350d-a025-4dc1-9038-8e13c3ec12dc",
                "message": "¿How are you?",
                "status": "SEEN",
                "username": "Chester López"
            }
        ],
        "name": null,
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "6c240de3-94e7-4b1c-9ef3-218dc71d8b0a"
            },
            {
                "id": "72b4350d-a025-4dc1-9038-8e13c3ec12dc"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need each user object to become:

```
{
    "id": "6c240de3-94e7-4b1c-9ef3-218dc71d8b0a"
    "email": "blabla@sssssss.eu",
    "image": null,
    "username": "John García"
}
```

I've tried doing this and many more tests but it does not work:

```
.map(function(chat){ // Get info from every user in every chat
    return chat("users").map(function(user) {
                return r.table("users").filter({id: user("id")})
                        .pluck("id", "email", "username", "image")
    })
})
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using concapmap. I hope this helps someone.

```
const id = req.id

r.table("chats").filter(chat => {
    return chat("users").contains(function (user) {
        return user("id").eq(id)
    })
}).map(chat => {
    return chat.merge({
        "messages":
            r.table("messages").eqJoin("user_id", r.table('users'))
                .zip()
                .filter(message => {
                    return message("user_id").eq(message("id")).and(message("chat_id").eq(chat("id")))
                })
                .pluck("id", "creation_date", "message", "email", "username", "status")
                .orderBy(r.asc('creation_date'))
                .coerceTo('array'),
        "users":
            chat("users").concatMap(user => {
                return r.table("users").filter(usu => {
                    return usu("id").eq(user("id"))
                }).pluck("id", "email", "username", "image")
            })
    })
})
.run(connection).then(function (cursor) {
    return cursor.toArray()
}).then(function (chats) {
    res.json({ success: 1, chats })
}).catch(function (err) {
        sendError(res, "Error -> " + err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about your data model, would be nice if you would attach some samples, to know which table has exactly what data. It would make easier to test the answers. That being said i think it should be something like this:

```
.map(function(chat){
    return chat.merge({
    "userDetails":
        r.table("users")
        .getAll(
            r.args(
               chat("users").map(function(doc){return doc("id")})
            )
        .pluck("id", "email", "username", "image")
    })
})
```

- you merge each "chat" document with an extra field "userDetails"
- in the userDetails Field you input the result of a subquery
- for this subquery you use the userIds that are present in your "chat" object
- you need to transform the "users" into an array so that it is compatible with the "getAll" function

I created on purpose an additional "userDetails" part in the "chat" object because i am not sure if overwriting the existing "users" would work.

Comment: It does not work, however I have managed to do it with concatmap. I put the solution on top. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The concatMap is a good idea. Altough I would try to use the getAll instead of the filter by Id because it supposed to be more performant.